# How to add information to an object in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
Flight myFlight = new Flight();
Label passL = new Label();
Label nameL = new Label();
Label ageL = new Label();
TextField passTF = new TextField();
TextField nameTF = new TextField();
TextField ageTF = new TextField();
Button addB = new Button("Add Passenger");
GridPane pane = new GridPane():
primaryStage.setTitle("");
pane.addColumn(0, passL, nameL, ageL, addB);
pane.addColumn(1, passTF, nameTF, ageTF);
Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

How can I add data from TextField to object(myFlight) by pressing the Add button?

Comment: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/javafx/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an action handling to the button. There you can extract the texts

```
addB.setOnAction(e -> {
    String tfText = passTF.getText();
    myFlight.setTf(tfText);
});
```

Comment: yeah I get that but how do I add the text to the object?

Comment: I edited the answer with an example of setting the value to `myFlight`. I don't know the class so I don't know any method of it.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked. Appreciate it.